# Stop browser from filling textboxes with details

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, textbox, browser-cache

I've run into a really annoying problem, and I'm hoping it's just a setting I've missed. I've got an ASP.NET application which allows users to enter their username/password in various places (e.g. login, change password, change username etc..). When I logged in, the browser asked if I would like to store the user details. Usually, I click 'no', but this time I decided to click 'yes'. Now, certain textboxes in my form are prefilled with the username or password. Is it possible to remove these, as they sometimes appear in textboxes which shouldn't be prefilled. I tried setting `AutoCompleteType=none` and `Text=''` but it still gets prefilled. The textboxes don't have much in common, except the same `CssClass` and, for password boxes, `TextMode=password`. The names are different, although sometimes they include the word `name` (e.g. fullName, userName). Is there a way to stop the browser from filling certain textboxes?

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
  <input type="text" name="Username" autocomplete="off">
```

You can also put this on the `form` tag. Note this does not work consistently in all browsers.

Comment: *facepalm* :/. I was using asp:textboxes and assumed the AutoCompleteType=none would do the same thing. Thanks! (I'll have to accept answer in 10 mins)

Comment: You can also use AutoCompleteType="disable" when using asp:TextBoxes

Comment: you can also use AutoCompleteType="Disabled" for Telerik controls

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for me was to include two fields, one for login and one for the password with display: none
`<input type="text" style="display: none"> 
<input type="password" style="display: none">`

Comment: <input type="text" style="display: none"> 
<input type="password" style="display: none">

Comment: Looks your answer need more explanation and better to edit your answer instead of putting code in comment

Answer (score 1):

if you set autocomplete="off"... the textbox will loose every words on its history...
but if you want to prevent browser saved usernames and password, the best way is to put these tags in top of your page:

```
<input type="text" style="display: none"> 
<input type="password" style="display: none">
```

Comment: I got the idea ! or may be we can add a new hidden input to the same form

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you happen to work in a much more updated framework, this code should work as expected. It has been 8 years ago and some of the answers here is outdated.

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Comment: @petezurich sorry about that, I find the code self explanatory.

Comment: Where is the reference? Why are you using Disabled versus off? How do the various browsers react to the two different settings? In no way is any of that self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed both: autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"

I am also using time picker from rome.js and preventing user from typing into textbox on keydown which complicated things.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReturnTime" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onkeydown="this.blur();" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
rome(txtReturnTime, { date: false, min: '07:15', max: '15:31', timeInterval: 900 });
</script>
```