# How to prevent browser from caching form fields?

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, browser-cache

I have a `textbox` in a form field that gets populated by the user.  However currently (in Firefox 10) the user can navigate away from the page, then come back, and the input will be populated with its previous value.  I think this creates for a confusing user experience, and would like to prevent it.

Is there a way to do this without manually resetting the value?  I have tried changing the response to not cache as well as setting `autocomplete='false'` with no luck.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try with `autocomplete="off"`, but it will not work with all browsers

PS: duplicate...

[Stop browser from filling textboxes with details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630986/stop-browser-from-filling-textboxes-with-details)

[Make page to tell browser not to cache/preserve input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699284/make-page-to-tell-browser-not-to-cache-preserve-input-values)

Comment: Does not seem to resolve the issue in FF10.

Comment: yes, you can't force a browser to do what you want ^^

Comment: Is there a cross-browser solution other than manually clearing the value with javascript?  Otherwise I might just make do with this.

Comment: what is your doctype ? officialy, autocomplete attribute appears only in html5 standard... But I think you should not clear these value if the users don't want to (except for security reasons)

Comment: Add this to input hidden fields as well.

Comment: Solution 4 here worked for me cross-browser:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/124608/How-avoid-the-cache-of-Textbox

Answer (score 11):

just add simple script in some global JS:

```
$("form :input").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: that is much faster way, thx

Comment: This is a reliable approach!! Nice!!

Answer (score 6):

> use meta  in head

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

or Use

```
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"; %>
<% Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); %>
<% Response.Expires = -1; %>
```

[microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067)