# Prevent caching of form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to prevent caching of your form? I've tried the autocomplete attribute on the form, and input elements. I've tried the meta head tags. Is there a way? Also, is it normal for forms to resubmit themselves after refreshing the page? Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question and preferably show the code that you have tried

Comment: What he said. Otherwise this is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587201/how-to-prevent-browser-from-caching-form-fields

Comment: How can I be more specific? I included all the methods I've used... `autocomplete="off"` and `<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">`.

Comment: I've tried the answer to the "duplicate" post. I know how to utilize the search function too man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent forms from resubmit themselves after refreshing the page using the Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) Pattern. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Not sure what language you are using but you can refer to this post: 
[How to prevent form resubmission when page is refreshed via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-via-php)

Comment: Solves the second problem. Thanks.