# Angular2 How do i clear the Form Value from Component.?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have my Form as shown below. when i open my form again it is holding on to the previous value in the text box. How di make sure it is cleared and starts fresh in case of Add New and populates current passed on object in case of edit.

```
   <form class="form-inline" #employerForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="employerName">Employer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employerName" placeholder="Employer Name ..." name="empName" [(ngModel)]="employer.name"
                       required>
            </div>
            <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!employerForm.valid">Create new Employer</button>-->
            <button *ngIf="mode=='edit'" (click)="saveEmployer('edit')" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save Changes</button>
            <button *ngIf="mode=='add'" (click)="saveEmployer('add')" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save Changes</button>
            <button  type="submit" (click)="close()" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!employerForm.valid">Cancel Changes & close</button>

        </form>
```

The code in the component is as follow

```
public employer: Employer = new Employer();

  close() {
   // this.employer = null;
    this.mode = null
    setTimeout(() => { this.employer = null }, 500);
    this.modal.close();
}
private saveEmployer(mode: string)
{
    this.mode = mode;
    if (this.mode == "add") {
        //Validate the Fields

       // let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.employer));
        this.employers.push(this.employer);
       // this.employer = null;
        this.close();
    }
    else if (this.mode = "edit"){
        //Find the Current Employer and update it.
       // this.employer = null;
        this.close();
    }
}
private editEmployer(_employer: Employer, mode: string) {
    debugger;
    this.mode = mode;
    if (this.mode == "edit") {
        this.modeMessage = "Edit Employer";
        this.employer = _employer;
        this.modal.open();
    }
    else if (this.mode == "add")
    {
        //employerForm.employer.name = "";
        this.modeMessage = "Add New Employer";
        this.employer = new Employer();
        this.modal.open();
    }
```

Comment: Provide plunker :)

Comment: Check [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587201/how-to-prevent-browser-from-caching-form-fields)

Comment: that did not help.

Comment: this.form.reset() ?