# How to prevent form caching in my website?

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, caching, cache-control

I'm using the following meta tags, but doesn't solve my problem

- Pragma  ->  no-cache
- cache-control  ->  no-cache,no-store

what is the difference of using this in meta tags and in headers form .htaccess

Please Suggest!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make page to tell browser not to cache/preserve input values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699284/make-page-to-tell-browser-not-to-cache-preserve-input-values)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630986/stop-browser-from-filling-textboxes-with-details and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587201/how-to-prevent-browser-from-caching-form-fields

Comment: Please try to search for an existing answer before creating a new post. More often than not you'll find that someone else has already faced the same problem - and has most likely already received an answer :)

Comment: @Lix - thanks for the quick reply and for you suggestion. Are there any tools to check if the form caching is off?

Comment: You could just test this on a few browsers that are known to implement autocomplete. Chrome and FireFox both implement this feature.

Comment: [Here is some more official documentation on how to disable autocomplete in forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

Comment: You may read for the concept of header http://stackoverflow.com/a/15050018/553964

Comment: @lix - if i use autocomplete="off" for form caching, the what is the use of meta tags pragma and cache-control?

Comment: That is for [caching of other HTTP resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_Caching_FAQ)