# Disable remember password alert in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css

how do i disable remember password alert in mozilla firefox through code

i tried this....

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
    < input type ="password" autocomplete : off />
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

this works on chrome and ie... but didn't works on mozilla...... anyone have solution please help me....!

and also tried to change password field to text feild then it working....
but for security purpose this not taken

Comment: You can check below URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: but its not properly working on mozilla

Comment: Learn syntax first. `<input type ="password" autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: you should try first........its not working on mozilla.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to disable `<input>`. This will work `<input type ="password" disabled="disabled"/>`. Add `disabled="disabled"`.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636724/how-to-prevent-autofill-of-previous-data-in-asptextbox/41712737#41712737

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers dropped the support for `autocomplete="off"`, see this [Is autocomplete="off" compatible with all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers/21348793#21348793)

A jQuery solution is given here [Input type=password, don't let browser remember the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468288/input-type-password-dont-let-browser-remember-the-password/26114274#26114274)